# inpainting for atlas/texture map

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, normal-map

How to fill empty/black area of the left one like the right one?
[image]

Any relevant links?

Comment: it's not clear what's your situation, between the first and the second picture it looks like there have been a different unwrap and the second unwrap seems to be more optimized

Comment: Now I'm researching topics related to parameterization and texture coordinates. This map is two different parameterizations of the same mesh. The island on the left is as few as possible (there is only one island here). I want to test the effect of inpainting on my algorithm.

Comment: For neural networks, it is better to learn image features with as few UV islands as possible. The left one is better than the right one, although the distortion on the left may be very large (I'm not sure. I'm trying to verify it).

Comment: The more you'll create seams the more you'll be able to fill the image and optimize the space, and the less the islands will be stretched, if this is what you ask

Comment: However, the more islands there are, the more chaotic it looks. It is not necessarily a good choice for neural networks.
Intuitively, the left one is more complete than the right one, without too much sense of fragmentation.

The main question here is there any algorithm to fill the left blank space. I don't know much about these areas and hope to get some introductory material.

Comment: For example, a part of the body has no texture. I want to complete the texture through image inpainting, I feel that the uv on the left is easier to train the network (under research).

Comment: I'm not famliar with this neural networks thing, I hope someone will be able to answer, I'm not sure you can have both a simple unwrap and an optimized space, without stretching, if this is what you're looking for, it sounds contradictory to me

Comment: NO: `both a simple unwrap and an optimized space, without stretching`.
Simple unwrap will certainly have more distortions, but I don't care about distortions, just simple UV island. Anyway, thanks~

Comment: yes but you care about space optimization if I understand correctly? it also sounds contradictory with minimal seams

Comment: I did parameterization with RIZOM, and the result is not very controllable.
Therefore, the priority of as few UV islands as possible is the highest, the degree of distortion and space optimization are not very important here.

But for the results I already have, I want to fill in the blanks with pixels first, so I ask a question here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136683/discussion-between-logwell-and-moonboots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def diffuse_color_with_mask(img_m, img_c, num_iter=1, ksize=3):
    """
    cv.findContours: http://t.zoukankan.com/wojianxin-p-12602490.html
    """
    img_m[img_m != 0] = 255

    hksize = ksize // 2
    k_range = range(-hksize, hksize + 1)

    #* expand
    img_m = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img_m, hksize, hksize, hksize, hksize, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0))
    img_c = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img_c, hksize, hksize, hksize, hksize, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0, 0, 0))

    for _ in range(num_iter):
        uu, vv = np.where(img_m == 0)

        #* remove border
        m = True
        m &= (uu >= hksize)
        m &= (uu < img_m.shape[0] - hksize)
        m &= (vv >= hksize)
        m &= (vv < img_m.shape[1] - hksize)
        uu = uu[m]
        vv = vv[m]

        #* select silhouette. only 3x3 patch
        m = False
        for tu in [-1, 0, 1]:
            for tv in [-1, 0, 1]:
                m |= (img_m[uu + tu, vv + tv] == 255)

        uu = uu[m]
        vv = vv[m]
        img_m[uu, vv] = 127  #! set silhouette value

        #* calc weights: 0/1 | sum and mean
        c = 0
        w = 0
        for tu in k_range:
            for tv in k_range:
                tw = (img_m[uu + tu, vv + tv] == 255).astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 1)
                tc = (img_c[uu + tu, vv + tv]).astype(np.float32)
                w += tw
                c += tw * tc
        img_c[uu, vv] = (c / w).astype(np.float32)
        img_m[img_m == 127] = 255  #!

    img_m = img_m[hksize:-hksize, hksize:-hksize]
    img_c = img_c[hksize:-hksize, hksize:-hksize].astype(np.uint8)

    return img_m, img_c


def TexturePadding(img_m0, img_c0, fac=1.25):
    """
    * question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265246/82691
        Here are some related keywords/links: 
            [Texture Padding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVsIIkJNkjM&ab_channel=malcolm341), 
            `Solidify` in [Free Plug-ins](http://www.flamingpear.com/free-trials.html) 
            and [Seam Fixing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9l8RfTvqyI&ab_channel=NamiNaeko); 
            [TexTools](https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender) for Blender.
    * reference:
        [inpainting for atlas/texture map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264966/inpainting-for-atlas-texture-map)
        [mipmap](https://substance3d.adobe.com/documentation/spdoc/padding-134643719.html)
        [distance transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421566/pixel-indexing-in-opencvs-distance-transform)
        [seamlessClone](https://learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/)
        [torch-interpol](https://github.com/balbasty/torch-interpol/issues/1)
    """

    assert 1 < fac < 1.5

    if np.all(img_m0 > 0):
        return img_c0

    img_m0[img_m0 != 0] = 255

    img_m0, img_c0 = diffuse_color_with_mask(img_m0, img_c0, 2)  #* diffuse 2 pixels (2x2 downsampling)

    img_m1 = img_m0.copy()
    img_c1 = img_c0.copy()
    while np.any(img_m1 == 0):
        img_m1 = cv2.resize(img_m1, (int(img_m1.shape[0] / fac), int(img_m1.shape[1] / fac)), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        img_c1 = cv2.resize(img_c1, (int(img_c1.shape[0] / fac), int(img_c1.shape[1] / fac)), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        img_m1[img_m1 != 255] = 0
        img_c1[img_m1 == 0] = 0
        img_m1, img_c1 = diffuse_color_with_mask(img_m1, img_c1, 2)

        img_m2 = img_m1.copy()
        img_c2 = img_c1.copy()
        while img_m2.shape[0] != img_m0.shape[0]:
            if (img_m0.shape[0] < img_m2.shape[0] * fac < img_m0.shape[0] * fac):
                img_shape = (img_m0.shape[0], img_m0.shape[1])
            else:
                img_shape = (int(img_m2.shape[0] * fac), int(img_m2.shape[1] * fac))
            img_m2 = cv2.resize(img_m2, img_shape, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
            img_c2 = cv2.resize(img_c2, img_shape, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

            img_m2[img_m2 != 255] = 0
            img_c2[img_m2 == 0] = 0

        nnz = np.nonzero(~img_m0 & img_m2)
        img_c0[nnz] = img_c2[nnz]
        img_m0 = img_m2

    return img_c0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path_img_m = "/home/lab0/Pictures/img_m.png"
    path_img_c = "/home/lab0/Pictures/img_c.jpg"

    img_m = cv2.imread(path_img_m, 0)
    img_c = cv2.imread(path_img_c, -1)

    img_c = TexturePadding(img_m, img_c, 1.35)
    cv2.imwrite(path_img_c[:-4] + "_tp.jpg", img_c)
```

input: img_m.png
[image: img_m.png]

input: img_c.jpg
[image: img_c.jpg]

output: img_c_tp.jpg
[image: img_c_tp.jpg]

Note: `jpg` will damage the pixels adjacent to the black background.
It is easy to generate some artifacts during diffusion!
But storing images with texture padding, `jpg` is still a good choice.

jpg:
[image]

[image]

png:
[image]

[image]